# Getting Facebook com.facebook.FacebookGraphObjectException: Factory can't proxy method error

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am getting this exception. Please find below the complete stack trace.

com.facebook.FacebookGraphObjectException: Factory can't proxy method: public abstract java.lang.String com.junobe.android.junowallet.SNS.u.a()
       at com.facebook.model.GraphObject$Factory.verifyCanProxyClass(SourceFile:290)
       at com.facebook.model.GraphObject$Factory.createGraphObjectProxy(SourceFile:216)
       at com.facebook.model.GraphObject$Factory.access$0(SourceFile:215)
       at com.facebook.model.GraphObject$Factory$GraphObjectProxy.proxyGraphObjectMethods(SourceFile:583)
       at com.facebook.model.GraphObject$Factory$GraphObjectProxy.invoke(SourceFile:521)
       at $Proxy0.cast()
       at com.facebook.Response.getGraphObjectAs(SourceFile:124)
       at com.junobe.android.junowallet.SNS.FacebookOpenGraphController.handleResponse(SourceFile:568)
       at com.junobe.android.junowallet.SNS.FacebookOpenGraphController.access$6(SourceFile:555)
       at com.junobe.android.junowallet.SNS.FacebookOpenGraphController$3.onPostExecute(SourceFile:522)
       at com.junobe.android.junowallet.SNS.FacebookOpenGraphController$3.onPostExecute(SourceFile:1)
       at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
       at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3685)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)

I am not getting this issue on all devices or all times. Identified this from crashlytics.

I have a hunch that it may be some proguard - obfuscation issue on Android.

I have added the following lines to in the proguard file (As per facebook Documentation):
-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature

Is there something I am missing .. Any assistance or solution would be welcome.

Comment: Any possible solutions?..Please do let me know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that I found that worked for me was to not obfuscate classes that extended facebook classes.  I had a bunch of files in one package so for all those files I just excluded them by adding this to my proguard-project.txt.

```
-keep class com.classes.extending.facebook.** { *; }
```